# C# Selenium Как заполнить два элемента сразу

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Всем Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, необходимо заполнить элементы на страницы, которые имеют одинаковые локаторы в моем случае это ".//input[contains(@name,'allowedQuantityDecreaseField')]", хотелось бы понимать как можно выйти из ситуации, хотелось посмотреть на примеры.

```
 List<IWebElement> increaseField = State.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//input[contains(@name,'allowedQuantityDecreaseField')]")).ToList();
                    if (AllowedQuantityDecrease != null)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < increaseField.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Form.Input(By.XPath(".//input[contains(@name,'allowedQuantityDecreaseField')]"), AllowedQuantityDecrease.ToString());
                        }
                    }
```

Код в моем случае такой, но из 2 элементов imput на странице, он заполняет только один, AllowedQuantityDecrease - поле в json файле, которое он парсит при вводе значений (шаблон)
Вопрос: Как заполнить сразу два элемента на странице?

Comment: Зачем вы повторно ищете элемент, если у вас уже коллекция найденных элементов?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду цикл тут не требуется?

Comment: Тут не требуется `By.XPath(".//input` внутри цикла, а требуется обращение к ранее найденному элементу, который лежит в коллекции (`increaseField[j]`, а ещё лучше использовать `foreach`)

Comment: извините, можете примерно описать, что имеете ввиду, я не понимаю, у меня ступор((((

Comment: 'foreach (var incres in increaseField)
                            {
                                Form.Input(incres, AllowedQuantityDecrease.ToString());
                            }'

Comment: все, проблему решил, СПАСИБО!